# How to get list of users which does not have Admin privilege ( Groovy + jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How to get a list of users who does not have Admin privilege ( Groovy + jenkins)

```
def inst = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull()
def strategy = inst.getAuthorizationStrategy()
def adminUserList = User.getAll().findAll { user ->
    strategy.hasPermission(user.id, Jenkins.ADMINISTER)
}
```

This is giving me a list of users who has ADMINISTER privilege. How to retrieve the list of all users who does not have ADMINISTER privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple negation helped to get the expected output :

```html
def inst = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull()
def strategy = inst.getAuthorizationStrategy()
def adminUserList = User.getAll().findAll { user ->
    !strategy.hasPermission(user.id, Jenkins.ADMINISTER)
}
```

Just changed "strategy.hasPermission" to "!strategy.hasPermission", this has given the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract the `adminUserList` from the `allUserList` and you will have the non admin users.

```
def inst = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull()
def strategy = inst.getAuthorizationStrategy()
def adminUserList = User.getAll().findAll { user ->
    strategy.hasPermission(user.id, Jenkins.ADMINISTER)
}
def allUserList = User.getAll()
print allUserList - adminUserList
```